Continue execution after PR is merged
I am running a script inside of AWS CodeBuild (which is a part of a State Machine). Script creates a pull request in GitHub. I need to stop/pause execution, and continue/resume it only when the PR was approved and merged. What would be the best way to achieve this?

You can try setting the integration pattern of the CodeBuild call to aws_stepfunctions.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN. The step will not finish until you send the result to the task token. The token is available on stepfunctions.JsonPath.taskToken. You can send it as an environment variable to your build and integrate it in the PR or somewhere safer. Once the PR is merged, you will tell the step function the step is done with something like the following:
aws stepfunctions send-task-success --task-token "$TASK_TOKEN"

That command can run in a GitHub Action triggered by the PR being merged.
If CDK complains because CodeBuildStartBuild step can't use the task token integration pattern, you can create your own custom step.
